# Should I generate a key from a hash for encryption?

Tags: encryption, rijndael

I am currently currently using Rijndael 256-bit in CBC mode to encrypt some data which needs to be sent elsewhere. In order to enhance security, I'm taking a randomly generated SHA-256 hash and using a formula to chop off different parts it to use the encryption key and initialization vector (of course, the hash is sent with the data). The formula to generate the key and IV is fairly basic, and because the code is written in PHP, it's coded into a user-accessible page. What I'm wondering is: is this more or less safe than having one constant key and/or IV?

Comment: If the key is sent with the data it's not encryption, just obfuscation.

Comment: A basic rule of cryptography is to never re-use the same key+IV combination. Which means that every message should have a different IV.

Comment: Thats really not a basic rule otherwise there wouldnt be the idea of a session key architected by very good cryptographers.  However, it is a "good" rule if you can indeed accomplish it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably NOT the way you wish to go.  In essence, it will take a good hacker not to long to figure out your mathematical formula for manipulating the HASH to generate your key and IV.  Thus you are essentially sending the keys to the kingdom along with the kingdom itself.

Generally the way this type of operation is done, is to generate a session key (could be the same way you are doing it now), but use a public key encryption method to encrypt that session key.  Then you use the public key encryption method to send the session key to the location your data is to be sent.  The receiver has the public key and can encrypt the comm. channel session key.

Now both sides have the comm. channel session key and your REAL data can be encrypted using this key as the session key has not been sent in the clear.

Rijindael is an example of a symmetric crypto algorithm, where public key crypto algorithms are asymmetric.  Examples of public key crypto algorithms are RSA, ECDSA (Crypto), etc....

Comment: Thanks for the info. Due to difficulties in getting the session key across, I've decided on using a single encryption key for the entire process. What are some ways I can make that safer?

Comment: You cant really, if you have a single key, then at some point in time enough data will have passed through the link to attempt a cryptocraphic attack.

Comment: One more thing. Is there any advantage to asymmetrically encrypting and sending the session ID to use as a symmetric encryption key to decrypt my data, as opposed to just public key encrypting the data itself?

Comment: Asymmetric essentially IS public key encryption!!!  The idea is that public key is asymmetric because the key to decrypt is different from the key to encrypt.  You (the secret holder) will encrypt the symmetric algorithm key using your private asymmetric key.  Nobody but you knows this private asymmetric key.  Everybody that you WANT to know can have your public decrypt key.  This protects now the symmetric session key as only those you want knowing about will actually know about it, and even they will never get your private asymmetric key, so you can always change the symmetric key.

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I meant was that I didn't understand why I should asymmetrically encrypt a key to symmetrically encrypt my data when asymmetrically encrypting my data (at least from my limited understanding of cryptology) works just as well, since the asymmetric encryption is the harder bit to break. After all, if they could break my asymmetrically encrypted data, they could break my asymmetrically encrypted key and then use that to steal my data anyway.

Comment: Normally this isnt done in many applications because asymmetric algorithms are VERY VERY SLOW. Because of this, you essentially do it once to encrypt the session key for a MUCH MUCH FASTER symmetric algorithm. Most symmetric algorithms are many times faster than asymmetric algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

On generating short-use keys.  Have a long term key.  Agree a date format with the receiver.  Each day concatenate your long term key with the day's date and hash it with SHA-256 to generate a day key for use on that date only:

```
dayKey <- SHA256("my very secret long term key" + "2012-06-27")
```

The receiver will have all the information they need to generate exactly the same key at their end.  Any attacker will know the date, but will not know the long term key.

You will need to agree protocols for around midnight and a few other details.

Change the long term key every month or two, depending on the amount of encrypted data you are passing.  The more data you pass, the more often you need to change the long term key.